# Varnish Cache giving me 503 error and no solution works

Tags: php, varnish

I recently set up Varnish Cache for my Magento 2 website. It works without issues on HTTPS links (port 443), but whenever I try to load a HTTP link, it returns a 503 error.

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 32934

Varnish cache server
```

Looking at the header, it shows that the HTTP website is at port 80 (Varnish is set to port 80), yet my VirtualHost is at port 8080.

I've tried so many solutions, including adding timeout, changing headers, rewrite rules etc., but nothing has helped. Could anyone here help maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know varnish, but could [this information](https://www.section.io/blog/varnish-cache-503-error-guru-meditation/) possibly help?

Comment: Thank you, @PaulT. Unfortunately, I've tried this and no luck

Comment: Last I heard, Varnish itself doesn’t support HTTPS. (If this has changed, I apologize for being out of date.) What are you using for TLS termination? Can you post your stack and basic VCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `varnishlog` to debug as described in https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/troubleshooting-varnish/#backend-errors.

Just run `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "VCL_call eq 'BACKEND_ERROR'"`  and paste the content here. I'll help you debug.

### Update after checking the logs

After checking the logs on https://pastebin.com/GeaVgkmw I found the following log line in `**  << BeReq    >> 16` on line 100:

```
--  FetchError     backend boot.default: unhealthy
```

Varnish doesn't even attempt to send a request to the backend, because it considers it unhealthy.

This is probably related to a failed health checking probe in your VCL.

You can run the following command to see more details about the health of your backends:

```
sudo varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health
```

Please also have a look at the `backend` and `probe` definitions in your VCL code. Don't hesitate to add your VCL config to the question along with the `Backend_health` logging output. This way we can figure out what Varnish is considering it unhealthy.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have the same error on another website (a staging website where I'm trying to test Varnish out). When I run that command, it simply freezes and it's not giving me anything until I stop it. Is there any other way I could check the log?

Also, am I supposed to have anything in etc/default/varnish ? The folder doesn't have that file, yet I've read that it should be there.

Comment: It has finally worked! [Here it is!](https://pastebin.com/GeaVgkmw)

Comment: @AsmirPekmic updated the answer based on the output of your logs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I run that command and it was showing the backend as sick since I had a 301 redirection. However, I edited the .vcl file and added an exception, so it works fine. However, now I have another issue, I am running into a redirect loop... 

When I disable Varnish and move Apache to port 80, everything works fine. But with Varnish? I'm getting constant redirects. Is there any chance you could help me with this or point me in the right direction on how to debug it? 

Many thanks!

Comment: @AsmirPekmic The redirect loop is a pretty common thing, but I do believe it belongs in a separate question. Create a new question, add log output from the redirect loop through `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"` and describe how your application enforces the redirections. Just make sure you tag the question with #varnish and I'll answer it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I posted a question with some basic info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490207/redirect-loop-in-apache-not-sure-how-to-fix-it), but I will soon switch my website back to Varnish and post the updated log.