# Redirect loop in Apache, not sure how to fix it

Tags: php, apache, redirect, varnish

I'm currently dealing with a redirect loop on Apache (Ubuntu 18.04) while trying to set up Varnish for my Magento website. If I turn Varnish off and move my Virtual Hosts to port 80, the website works fine. However, it's currently giving me the infinite loop [which can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar4Lg.jpg)

My .conf file for port 8080:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName fontele.online
ServerAlias www.fontele.online
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
Redirect permanent / https://fontele.online/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

My conf file for port 443:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName fontele.online
ServerAlias www.fontele.online
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/ 
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

SSLEngine On
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/fontele.online/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/fontele.online/privkey.pem
```

.htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I really don't understand where the www redirection comes from. Should I just remove ServerAlias? I am also unsure about the constant HTTPS redirections. On my live domain, I solved this problem without any problems, but I have no idea how to set it up properly with Varnish. I assume that it's up to ProxyPass or something like that?

Any help would be welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

The solution is very simple. Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header append Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto
```

This will append the `X-Forwarded-Proto` value to the `Vary` header. Varnish will use these values to create separate cache objects for the various values of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header.

This will either be `https` or an empty value for regular HTTP traffic.

It would also be a good idea to add `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"` to the `<VirtualHost *:8080>`.

### Why are you getting this redirect loop?

I also want to explain what's going on and why you're stuck in this loop.

Varnish doesn't make a difference between HTTP or HTTPS when it comes to identifying objects in the cache.

Varnish uses 2 request properties to create the cache object hash:

- The URL (`/contact` for example)
- The `Host` header (`fontele.online` for example)

If access the `http://` version, you'll get the `302` redirect, which will end up in the cache.

However, if you access the `https://` version, you'll hit the same object and get the same redirect, despite using a differente protocol.

Thanks the `Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto` response header you can tell Varnish to store 2 different versions based on the value of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header.

### An alternative solution using VCL

If you don't want to tackle this problem in your web server, you can also issue the `Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto` response header in the `vcl_backend_response` subroutine of your VCL code.

This is the code you need to make this happen:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if(beresp.http.Vary) {
        set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", X-Forwarded-Proto";
    } else {
        set beresp.http.Vary = "X-Forwarded-Proto";
    }
}
```